# How to share windows registry on remote machine?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, registry

Is it possible to share windows registry on remote machine? Or we can keep in synch two machines windows registry.

Please help..

- Kartik

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [article](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5173421.html) on how to manage a remote registry. You didnt post which windows you are using, so i just assumed it was Windows XP Pro.

I dont know how to configure windows to synchronize a particular key in the registry. I reckon you could write a program to just read the remote keys and write into the local keys.

Comment: I was added tag Windows server 2008.